# videojs changing audio tracks programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, video.js, mediaelement

I've read the documentation twice and haven't found a way to do this. `videojs` on its own cannot do this, this is mentioned in the docs so I have the `hls` plugin which should be able to do it yet I can't find anything related to this.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code?

Comment: Why none of these links helps? https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/blob/master/docs/multiple-alternative-audio-tracks.md, https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/blob/master/examples/multiple-alternative-audio-tracks/index.html, https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/audio-tracks.md ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of changing source video track with video.js:

```js
/* video player setup */
vPlayer = videojs('my_video', {
  techOrder: ["html5", "youtube"],
  autoplay: false,
  sources: [{
    type: "video/mp4",
    src: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
  }]
});
vPlayer.on('playing', function(e) {
  $("#info").html("playing...<br>url: " + vPlayer.currentSrc() + "<br>type:" + vPlayer.currentType());
});

/* available videos */
var vids = [{
    type: "video/mp4",
    src: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
  },
  {
    type: "video/mp4",
    src: "https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4"
  },
  {
    type: "video/youtube",
    src: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkGeOWYOFoA"
  }
];

playVideo = function(n) {
  vPlayer.src(vids[n]);
  vPlayer.play();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/6.7/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/6.7/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/videojs/videojs-youtube/c4be481f/dist/Youtube.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="my_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="400">
</video>
<hr>
<button onclick="playVideo(0)">play 0 (mp4)</button>
<button onclick="playVideo(1)">play 1 (mp4)</button>
<button onclick="playVideo(2)">play 2 (youtube)</button>
<hr>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Here is also a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/w7yah2vo/

Comment: by "track" I meant audio track not the video source